# worklight auto-generated android folder does not run on avd

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

i have installed ibm worklight studio (enterprise edition) 5.0.5v on windows server 2008 and i have also configured it with the latest android sdk(api 17, android 4.2) and the latest adt plugin (22.0v). when i create a new worklight project "HelloWorld", i build it and preview on browser trough the worklight console normally. when i add a worklight environment (android) to the project "HelloWorld", the auto-generated "HelloWorldHelloWorldApplicationAndroid" is created but when i do right-click on "Run as -> Android Application" it shows me an error (or more). the virtual android device shows me "Unfortunately HelloWorldApplication has stopped". i am looking for resolve this problem, on the logcat i did a screenshot

[screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/2vbaomt/5)

Someone has encountered this kind of problem? Thanks to anyone give me a tip, i hope i was accurate on describing the problem

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to a change Google has made in this version of ADT.
It affects users of ADT v22 only. Worklight will have a built-in fix for this in its next release.

In the meanwhile, to fix this (on a per-project basis):

1. Right-click on your generated Android project and choose "properties".
2. From the left pane, choose "Java Build Path'
3. Tick the "Android Private Libraries" checkbox
4. Refresh the project / re-build the app

The app should now work in the device.