# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.x - Hybrid Android application can't run on real device

Tags: android, adb, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a Worklight application with the Android environment and tried running it. It is working fine in the Android Emulator but when I try to run it in an Android device it shows an error:

> The application has unfortunately stopped

Can anybody help me regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably installed ADT v22.
I have provided an answer for this problem in this question: [worklight auto-generated android folder does not run on avd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732409/worklight-auto-generated-android-folder-does-not-run-on-avd/16732630#16732630)

This happens due to a change Google has made in this version of ADT.
It affects users of ADT v22 only. Worklight will have a built-in fix for this in Worklight v6.0.

In the meanwhile, follow these instructions (on a per-project basis):

1. Right-click on your generated Android project and choose
   "properties"
2. From the left pane, choose "Java Build Path'
3. Tick the "Android Private Libraries" checkbox
4. Refresh the project / re-build the app

The app should now successfully launch in the device.