# IBM Worklight - Android SDK - Emulator deployment issue - Unfortunately, 'app' has stopped

Tags: android, adt, ibm-mobilefirst

I am on Mac 10.8.3, Eclipse Juno with latest Android SDK 22.0.0, IBM Worklight version 5.0.6.1.

I have made a small Mobile App using Dojo Mobile & HTML5/CSS3 in Worklight but having hard time to deploy on Android Emulator though it's running fine in Xcode.

Here is the logcat, looks like something goes weird from Java end hence getting the runtime exceptions.

```
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.TD/com.TD.TD}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.TD.TD
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.TD.TD
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
05-28 09:56:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  ... 11 more
```

Idan, tried out the same tick but didn't help, below is the logcat output.

```
05-28 10:35:49.564: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:35:49.834: E/Samsung TTS(5063): onLoadLanguage() - lang : eng, country : USA, variant : 
05-28 10:35:49.834: E/Samsung TTS(5063): onIsLanguageAvailable() - lang : eng, country : USA, variant : , iResult : 1
05-28 10:35:49.839: E/Samsung TTS(5063): onLoadLanguage() - LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE
05-28 10:35:49.844: E/Samsung TTS(5063): onLoadLanguage() - lang : eng, country : USA, variant : f01
05-28 10:35:49.999: E/Samsung TTS(5063): onCreate() - Samsung TTS package (released - 2012.06.14)
05-28 10:35:49.999: E/(5063): Samsung TTS Engine - initialize() : Samsung TTS Engine (released - 2012.07.11)
05-28 10:35:49.999: E/(5063): Samsung TTS Engine - initialize() : ro.product.manufacturer - samsung
05-28 10:35:52.429: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:35:52.739: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:35:53.399: E/SensorManager(5281): thread start
05-28 10:35:54.104: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:35:57.729: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:35:57.914: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:35:59.454: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:02.824: E/PowerManagerService(2008): WakeLock : binderDied()
05-28 10:36:02.824: E/PowerManagerService(2008): WakeLock : binderDied()
05-28 10:36:02.824: E/PowerManagerService(2008): WakeLock : binderDied()
05-28 10:36:08.074: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:08.474: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:09.364: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:10.194: E/PowerManagerService(2008): WakeLock : binderDied()
05-28 10:36:11.619: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): On change is called.false
05-28 10:36:11.619: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): URI of the playlistcontent://media/external/audio/playlists
05-28 10:36:11.619: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Content resolver is not null
05-28 10:36:11.639: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Count1mCount1
05-28 10:36:11.639: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Neither deleted nor added. Could be rename
05-28 10:36:11.639: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): It is not renamed
05-28 10:36:12.299: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): setDataSource fd=45, offset=0, length=576460752303423487
05-28 10:36:12.299: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): calculated length = 17294
05-28 10:36:15.789: E/SensorManager(6762): thread start
05-28 10:36:16.614: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:16.929: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:18.584: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:18.719: E/Watchdog(2008): !@Sync 2284
05-28 10:36:20.699: E/MtpService(22311): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
05-28 10:36:20.704: E/MtpService(22311): battPlugged Type : 2
05-28 10:36:23.319: E/a(7151): Metric [API Handler - SubscribePushNotification (mobile)] Value [984] (ms)
05-28 10:36:25.534: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): On change is called.false
05-28 10:36:25.534: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): URI of the playlistcontent://media/external/audio/playlists
05-28 10:36:25.534: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Content resolver is not null
05-28 10:36:25.599: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Count1mCount1
05-28 10:36:25.599: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Neither deleted nor added. Could be rename
05-28 10:36:25.599: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): It is not renamed
05-28 10:36:25.774: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): setDataSource fd=45, offset=0, length=576460752303423487
05-28 10:36:25.774: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): calculated length = 17294
05-28 10:36:26.964: E/a(7244): Metric [API Handler - SubscribePushNotification (mobile)] Value [951] (ms)
05-28 10:36:26.969: E/a(7244): Metric [API Handler - SubscribePushNotification (mobile)] Value [834] (ms)
05-28 10:36:30.169: E/WifiP2pStateTracker(2008): getNetworkInfo : NetworkInfo: type: wifi_p2p[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false
05-28 10:36:30.374: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:30.704: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:31.329: E/WifiP2pStateTracker(2008): getNetworkInfo : NetworkInfo: type: wifi_p2p[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false
05-28 10:36:31.344: E/WifiP2pStateTracker(2008): getNetworkInfo : NetworkInfo: type: wifi_p2p[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false
05-28 10:36:31.469: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:35.834: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:36.139: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:39.624: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): On change is called.false
05-28 10:36:39.624: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): URI of the playlistcontent://media/external/audio/playlists
05-28 10:36:39.629: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Content resolver is not null
05-28 10:36:39.709: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Count1mCount1
05-28 10:36:39.709: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Neither deleted nor added. Could be rename
05-28 10:36:39.709: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): It is not renamed
05-28 10:36:39.884: E/DBG_FMMDM(7678): Warning!!! [v1_1211_2_1][Line:590][xdbLawmoSetRegistration] java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 10:36:40.119: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): setDataSource fd=45, offset=0, length=576460752303423487
05-28 10:36:40.119: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): calculated length = 17294
05-28 10:36:44.719: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:48.629: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:48.719: E/Watchdog(2008): !@Sync 2285
05-28 10:36:49.049: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:36:53.099: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): On change is called.false
05-28 10:36:53.099: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): URI of the playlistcontent://media/external/audio/playlists
05-28 10:36:53.099: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Content resolver is not null
05-28 10:36:53.109: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Count1mCount1
05-28 10:36:53.109: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Neither deleted nor added. Could be rename
05-28 10:36:53.109: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): It is not renamed
05-28 10:36:53.329: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): setDataSource fd=45, offset=0, length=576460752303423487
05-28 10:36:53.329: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): calculated length = 17294
05-28 10:36:53.519: E/SensorManager(7854): thread start
05-28 10:37:00.844: E/MtpService(22311): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
05-28 10:37:00.844: E/MtpService(22311): battPlugged Type : 2
05-28 10:37:06.579: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): On change is called.false
05-28 10:37:06.579: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): URI of the playlistcontent://media/external/audio/playlists
05-28 10:37:06.579: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Content resolver is not null
05-28 10:37:06.699: E/PowerManagerService(2008): WakeLock : binderDied()
05-28 10:37:06.764: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Count1mCount1
05-28 10:37:06.764: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Neither deleted nor added. Could be rename
05-28 10:37:06.764: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): It is not renamed
05-28 10:37:06.794: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): setDataSource fd=45, offset=0, length=576460752303423487
05-28 10:37:06.794: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): calculated length = 17294
05-28 10:37:06.824: E/MediaScannerService(8051): Exception in handleMessage
05-28 10:37:06.824: E/MediaScannerService(8051): android.os.DeadObjectException
05-28 10:37:06.824: E/MediaScannerService(8051):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
05-28 10:37:06.824: E/MediaScannerService(8051):    at android.media.IMediaScannerListener$Stub$Proxy.scanCompleted(IMediaScannerListener.java:100)
05-28 10:37:06.824: E/MediaScannerService(8051):    at com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(MediaScannerService.java:282)
05-28 10:37:06.824: E/MediaScannerService(8051):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 10:37:06.824: E/MediaScannerService(8051):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 10:37:06.824: E/MediaScannerService(8051):    at com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService.run(MediaScannerService.java:224)
05-28 10:37:06.824: E/MediaScannerService(8051):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-28 10:37:13.299: E/PowerManagerService(2008): WakeLock : binderDied()
05-28 10:37:13.299: E/PowerManagerService(2008): WakeLock : binderDied()
05-28 10:37:13.299: E/PowerManagerService(2008): WakeLock : binderDied()
05-28 10:37:14.974: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:37:18.724: E/Watchdog(2008): !@Sync 2286
05-28 10:37:20.364: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): On change is called.false
05-28 10:37:20.364: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): URI of the playlistcontent://media/external/audio/playlists
05-28 10:37:20.364: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Content resolver is not null
05-28 10:37:20.389: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Count1mCount1
05-28 10:37:20.389: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): Neither deleted nor added. Could be rename
05-28 10:37:20.389: E/MTPPlaObsrvr(22311): It is not renamed
05-28 10:37:20.434: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): setDataSource fd=45, offset=0, length=576460752303423487
05-28 10:37:20.434: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(1733): calculated length = 17294
05-28 10:37:23.134: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:37:23.519: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:37:29.489: E/DBG_DM(8369): Warning!!! [v5_1211_3_1][Line:2023][xdmCheckSystemRooting] Device is ok
05-28 10:37:29.589: E/DBG_DM(8369): Warning!!! [v5_1211_3_1][Line:2023][xdmCheckSystemRooting] Device is ok
05-28 10:37:29.639: E/DBG_DM(8369): Warning!!! [v5_1211_3_1][Line:2023][xdmCheckSystemRooting] Device is ok
05-28 10:37:29.699: E/DBG_DM(8369): Warning!!! [v5_1211_3_1][Line:2023][xdmCheckSystemRooting] Device is ok
05-28 10:37:32.539: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:37:33.959: E/PowerManagerService(2008): WakeLock : binderDied()
05-28 10:37:36.384: E/PowerManagerService(2008): WakeLock : binderDied()
05-28 10:37:40.379: E/SensorManager(9016): thread start
05-28 10:37:40.934: E/MtpService(22311): In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
05-28 10:37:40.934: E/MtpService(22311): battPlugged Type : 2
05-28 10:37:42.169: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:37:42.669: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:37:48.724: E/Watchdog(2008): !@Sync 2287
05-28 10:37:59.459: E/PushClient(1895): [a] MCC is same
05-28 10:38:09.664: E/a(9549): Metric [API Handler - SubscribePushNotification (mobile)] Value [1144] (ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems very similar to:

- [IBM Worklight 5.0.6.x - Hybrid Android application can't run on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783293/ibm-worklight-hybrid-android-application-cant-run-on-real-device)
- [worklight auto-generated android folder does not run on avd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732409/worklight-auto-generated-android-folder-does-not-run-on-avd/16732630#16732630)

This happens due to a change Google has made in this version of ADT.
It affects users of ADT v22 only. Worklight will have a built-in fix for this in its next release.

In the meanwhile, follow these instructions (on a per-project basis):

1. Right-click on your generated Android project and choose
   "properties"
2. From the left pane, choose "Java Build Path'
3. Tick the "Android Private Libraries" checkbox
4. Refresh the project / re-build the app

From the Android SDK manager, also make sure you have installed the Android Build Tools.

The app should now successfully launch in the device and/or emulator.

Comment: Idan still no luck after making the change, getting blank while screen on Emulator even deploy the same into my android phone and it's showing the same message "Unfortunately, 'app' has stopped".

Comment: This is a new project of a sample or something? Try with a new Worklight project, change nothing in it except for the steps in my answer. Tell me how that goes.

Comment: sure, give me sometime, will revert you, by the way, it's a new project.

Comment: @MohammedArif, change luck?

Comment: Due to some other project requirement, had to change the machine/platform, now I am on OSX and don't see the issue, of course that's not the resolution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

Did as Idan wrote after updating ADT to 22.0.1.
Make sure you are uninstaling the old app from Android emulator and rebuild the Worklight app before testing.

Yaniv.

Comment: Tried that too but no luck still.

Comment: @MohammedArif, from the Android SDK manager, also make sure you have installed the Android Build Tools.